# Non-isomorphic product of two groups

Tags: group-theory, matrices, finite-groups

I know this is a simple question, but I'm not able to reason it out right now.

Why is $\pm I_n \not\cong \pm I_n \times \pm I_n$?

Comment: On the right, you have two slots to place a sign, on the left, only one.

Comment: Is "$\pm I_n$" supposed to denote a group here? Please explain.

Comment: @Henning Makholm Yes, $\pm I_n$ denotes the positive or negative identity matrix.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer Could you please clarify?

Comment: The group on the left has 2 elements, and the group on the right* has 4.

Comment: On the right hand side, you have pairs of matrices. Each component of the pair has a sign, independent of the other, so you have $(+,+),\, (+,-),\,(-,+),\,(-,-)$. On the left, you have only one matrix you can give a sign.

Comment: @Anonymous: One would usually write that with set brackets as $\{\pm I_n\}$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main reason $\{\pm I_n\}$ is not isomorphic to $\{\pm I_n\} \times \{\pm I_n\}$ is because they have a different number of elements.  Isomorphisms are *bijective* homomorphisms, so only groups of the same order can be isomorphic.

E.g. when $n=2$, we have:

$$\{\pm I_n\}=\left\{\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \\ \end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix} -1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \\ \end{bmatrix}\right\}$$
and
$$\{\pm I_n\} \times \{\pm I_n\}=\left\{\left(\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \\ \end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \\ \end{bmatrix}\right),\left(\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \\ \end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix} -1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \\ \end{bmatrix}\right),\left(\begin{bmatrix} -1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \\ \end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \\ \end{bmatrix}\right),\left(\begin{bmatrix} -1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \\ \end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix} -1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \\ \end{bmatrix}\right)\right\}.$$

We do, however, have $$\{\pm I_1\} \cong \{\pm I_2\} \cong \{\pm I_3\} \cong \cdots.$$